# type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#

I have the code below in a .cs file and I am coming across the errors below, any help would be appreciated.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Assignment2.Models
{
    public class TicketBookingEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Performance> Performances { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Production> Productions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'DbSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   4   The type or namespace name 'DbSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: **are you missing an assembly reference?**

Comment: Try adding the reference. Right click on the solution file, click on add reference, then look for the appropriate dll.

Comment: adding a reference is totally different to writing `using Some.Namespace;`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure your project contains a reference to **EntityFramework.dll**.
See the topic **To add a reference in Visual C#** in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you don't know how to add a reference.

Comment: hi, thanks, I added the reference System.Data.Entity and this solved this error however I still have the errors on the other 3, help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user1300580: There is no reference "System.Data.Entity", it simply doesn't exist. There is a *namespace* with that name. The *reference* is a DLL named EntityFramework.dll. So what did you really do?

Comment: I am unable to find the reference EntityFramework is that the xact name of this referenece?

Comment: @user1300580: Yes, it is the exact name. What framework are you targeting with your Project? .NET Framework 2?

Comment: @user1300580: Please tell us what the issue was.

Comment: I hadn't got the EntityFramework it wouldnt show so I managed to take it from another project I had open, seamed to do the trick...

Comment: Jeez, turns out I had different versions of Entity Framework in different assemblies. This pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Try looking for your missing references in Object Browser.