# System.Web not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 for my Windows Phone App Development. I have to use

```
System.Web.UI.Page
```

in my code, but when I try to include it with:

```
using System.Web.UI;
```

It gives this error:
*The type or namespace name Web doesnot exist in namespace System*

When I search for it in Object Browser, its there. How can I use it?

Comment: Add a reference to the .NET Assembly?

Comment: Assuming you get the reference working, I can't think of a good reason to have an instance of an ASP.NET Web Forms page in a Windows Phone app. Why are you doing that?

Comment: plus I'm sure this has been asked before!

Comment: possible duplicate of [type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140931/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace)

Comment: Windows Phone App's by design target a subset of the .NET base class library. Even though they are in the same namespace, under the hood, there are two different DLLs that provide the various components.

Comment: @mason I was looking for some way to call JavaScript Functions of my WebPage from C# code without WebBrowser element. I came across a link on StackOverflow which suggested a method using Page and some other thing.

Comment: @PratPor I can't imagine how that would work. Do you have a link to the tutorial?

Comment: @mason I was referring this link. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931936/call-javascript-function-from-c-sharp
I am not sure if it will work. But being naive to wp8, I thought of giving it a try

Comment: No, that will not work. That's for an ASP.NET context, where the code is running on a web server. It won't work from a Windows Phone project. Why do you want to call a JavaScript function on a webpage anyways?

Comment: @mason Actually I am using a WebBrowser element, defined in MainPage.xaml file to render my website. To call JS functions of my site, I am using `WebBrowser.InvokeScript()` method from MainPage.xaml.cs. But now some part of my App lies in AnotherClass.cs file. And I have to call some JS Functions from here also but now I cannot access the WebBrowser element

Comment: Then pass the WebBrowser element as a function parameter to the function in `AnotherClass.cs`. Using ASP.NET WebForms `Page` is barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @mason Sure I will try doing that. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your project, you need to [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to the [`System.Web`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) assembly which is located under:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web`

Also make sure you are targeting the full .NET Framework 4.0, not the Client Profile, as it does not contain the `System.Web` namespace.

Comment: Hi. Its giving this error when I tried adding it: Type universe cannot resolve assembly.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15589921/1218281) answer, it may not be available in your case. EDIT: `System.Web` is unavailable in Windows Phone (See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10899337/1218281))

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Will look for an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the assembly `System.Web` to your project references.